# is it possible, to add auto incremental classes to a list by using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

is it possible, to add auto incremental classes to a list

```
<ul id="list">
 <li>Element 1</li>
 <li>Element 2</li>
 <li>Element 3</li>
 <li>Element 4</li>
 <li>Element 5</li>
</ul>
```

Now, If I hover on Element 3 then, add auto incremental classes to `li` like example below...

```
<ul id="list">
 <li class="left2">Element 1</li>
 <li class="left1">Element 2</li>
 <li>Element 3</li>
 <li class="right1">Element 4</li>
 <li class="right2">Element 5</li>
</ul>
```

Again if hover on Element 1 then, add auto incremental classes to `li` like example below...

```
<ul id="list">
 <li>Element 1</li>
 <li class="right1">Element 2</li>
 <li class="right2">Element 3</li>
 <li class="right3">Element 4</li>
 <li class="right4">Element 5</li>
</ul>
```

sorry about my poor English. Thank you.

Comment: what if you hover on element 2?

Comment: If I hover on element 2 then add class for element 1 
<li class="left1">Element 1</li>
<li>Element 2</li>
<li class="right1">Element 3</li>
<li class="right2">Element 4</li>
<li class="right3">Element 5</li>

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on example, I cleared all the class in `<li>` when mouseenter anyone of the `<li>` and add new class for them.

left1+n will add to previous all `<li>` and right1+n will add to next all `<li>`

```
$("#list > li").on("mouseenter", function(){
    $("#list > li").attr("class", "");

  $(this).prevAll("li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('left' + (i+1));
  });
  $(this).nextAll("li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('right' + (i+1));
  });
});
```

Comment: Ooo My God, Its perfect. Thanks a lot....... 
I don't have point so that I can't review your answer

Comment: @M.Kaisar Welcome :)

Answer (score 8):

```js
$('li').hover(function() {
$('li').removeClass();
  var next = $(this).nextAll();
  next.each(function(i, v) {
    $(this).addClass('right' + (i+1))

  })

  var prev = $(this).prevAll();
  prev.each(function(i, v) {
    $(this).addClass('left' + (i+1))

  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
  <li>Element 4</li>
  <li>Element 5</li>
</ul>
```

Use [.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) and [.nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

> Description: Get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.
>
> Description: Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

then iterate on the li and assign the index. make sure to remove the li classes so it wont stack up

Comment: You should use `i+1` because count should be from `1` not from `0`.

Comment: @M.Kaisar glad it works for you you can tick the check mark so we can close the OP :)